# ServiceStack OrmLite Join Issues

Tags: c#, sql, servicestack, left-join, ormlite-servicestack

I'm having a problem with ServiceStack OrmLite for SQL Server in a Visual Studio 2013 C# project. My problem is that I'm trying to use the SqlExpression builder and it's not capturing my table schema and the generated SQL code is not correct. When I run the code, I get a System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException that says "Invalid object name 'ReportPages'."

I'm using the latest NuGet version of ServiceStack.OrmLite, which is version 4.0.24.

Let me start with the table setup. Note that I removed the foreign keys for convenience:

```
-- Create the report pages table.
CREATE TABLE [MicroSite].[ReportPages](
    [ReportPageID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
    [Template] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [AccessLevel] [int] NOT NULL,
    [AssignedEmployeeId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Disabled] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [Deleted] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [ReportSectionID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Index] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Cover] [bit] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.ReportSections] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
(
    [ReportPageID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO


-- Create the report sections table.
CREATE TABLE [MicroSite].[ReportSections](
    [ReportSectionID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [ReportID] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.ReportSectionGroups] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
(
    [ReportSectionID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO


-- Create the report editables table.
CREATE TABLE [MicroSite].[Editables](
    [EditableID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Index] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Content] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Styles] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [Type] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ReportPageID] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Editables] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
(
    [EditableID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

So my tables basically look like this:

[image: tables]

Here are my POCOs:

```
[Alias("ReportPages")]
[Schema("MicroSite")]
public partial class MicrositeReportPage : IHasId<int>
{
    [Required]
    public int AccessLevel { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int AssignedEmployeeId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public bool Cover { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public bool Deleted { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public bool Disabled { get; set; }

    [Alias("ReportPageID")]
    [AutoIncrement]
    [PrimaryKey]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int Index { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Alias("ReportSectionID")]
    [Required]
    public int ReportSectionId { get; set; }

    public string Template { get; set; }
}

[Alias("ReportSections")]
[Schema("MicroSite")]
public class MicrositeReportSection : IHasId<int>
{
    [Alias("ReportSectionID")]
    [AutoIncrement]
    [PrimaryKey]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Alias("ReportID")]
    [Required]
    public int ReportId { get; set; }
}

[Alias("Editables")]
[Schema("MicroSite")]
public partial class MicrositeEditable : IHasId<int>
{
    public string Content { get; set; }

    [Alias("EditableID")]
    [AutoIncrement]
    [PrimaryKey]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int Index { get; set; }

    [Alias("ReportPageID")]
    [Required]
    public int ReportPageId { get; set; }

    public string Styles { get; set; }

    [Alias("Type")]
    [Required]
    public int TypeId { get; set; }
}
```

The actual SQL statement I want to generate is this:

```
SELECT  e.EditableID
      , e.[Index]
      , e.Content
      , e.Styles
      , e.Type
      , e.ReportPageID
FROM
    MicroSite.ReportSections AS rs
LEFT JOIN
    MicroSite.ReportPages AS rp ON rp.ReportSectionID = rs.ReportSectionID AND rp.[Index] = 24
LEFT JOIN
    MicroSite.Editables AS e ON e.ReportPageID = rp.ReportPageID
WHERE
    rs.ReportID = 15
```

Here is my C# code:

```
var query = db.From<MicrositeReportSection>()
              .LeftJoin<MicrositeReportSection, MicrositeReportPage>((section, page) => section.Id == page.ReportSectionId)
              .LeftJoin<MicrositeReportPage, MicrositeEditable>((page, editable) => page.Id == editable.ReportPageId && page.Index == 24)
              .Where<MicrositeReportSection>(section => section.ReportId == 15);

var sql = query.ToSelectStatement();
var result = db.Select<MicrositeEditable>(query)
```

The generated SQL statement from the sql variable looks like this (I formatted it for readability):

```
SELECT
    "ReportSectionID",
    "Name",
    "ReportID"
FROM
    "MicroSite"."ReportSections"
LEFT JOIN
    "ReportPages"  ON ("ReportSections"."ReportSectionID" = "ReportPages"."ReportSectionID")
LEFT JOIN "Editables"
    ON (("ReportPages"."ReportPageID" = "Editables"."ReportPageID") AND ("ReportPages"."Index" = 24))
WHERE
    ("ReportSections"."ReportID" = 15)
```

First, the left joins are missing the schema name, which makes the SQL statement incorrect. Second, what's going on in the select statement? Those aren't the columns from the MicrositeEditable table. Am I doing this correctly or is this an actual bug with OrmLite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I submitted a ticket with the development team and this is now fixed in version 4.0.25.